# Convert a dummy image to readable one using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing

I want to convert this dummy image to plain image and make its text to be readable using Javascript
[image]

I tried to use this code

```
 var temp=document.createElement("canvas");
var image0=document.getElementById("image0");
var image=new Image();
image.onload=function(){
    recolorImage(image);
}
image.src = image0.src;

function recolorImage(img){
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var w = img.width;
    var h = img.height;

    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
    for (var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4)
      {
        var checkColor=243;
        if (imageData.data[i] > checkColor && imageData.data[i + 1] > checkColor && imageData.data[i + 2] > checkColor) {
            imageData.data[i] = 255;
            imageData.data[i + 1] = 255;
            imageData.data[i + 2] = 255;
        } else {
            imageData.data[i] = 0;
            imageData.data[i + 1] = 0;
            imageData.data[i + 2] = 0;
        }
      }
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    var img1 = document.getElementById("image0");
    img1.src = c.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

and this a result
[image]
As you can see it's still need to be repaired, please help, Thanks a lot